# How can I handle each message/ping received by WirelessHost and how can i retrieve statistics of that packet?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have a simple network set up, where i have two wireless hosts that ping each other. I want to achieve something like when either one receives a ping, i can print("ping received") or something. Basically allowing me to have control of each ping sequence.

My final goal is to print out ping statistics for each ping / message. For example, the Round trip time for each ping. I am using PingApp for the ping. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

I would first look into the documentation of the PingApp and check all the parameters in the PingApp.ned file. Then probably would set the `printPing` parameter value to `true`.

And finally, you should take a look at the statistics definition in the NEd file, that covers rtt, numLost and outOforderArrivals if you want to do analysis on these and not just a printout.